# webservice returns rounded number instead of decimal

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a web service that returns a decimal value into my json string but it rounds it off on numbers that are 400.00 to 400 instead, but if it has 400.50 it returns 400.50 which is what i want how do i return a value that is 400 to 400.00 in that format

**Error**

```
{"Message":"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method \u0027System.String ToString(System.String)\u0027 method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.","
```

**Code**

```
    Products = (
    from p in db.Products where p.DepartmentId == qDepartment.Id
    join i in db.ProductImages on p.Id equals i.ProductId into products
    from x in products.Where(y => y.Dimension == "180X180")
    select new Product
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        Title = p.Title,
        ShortDescription = p.ShortDescription,
        Brand = p.Brand,
        Model = p.Model,
        Image = x.Path,
        FriendlyUrl = p.FriendlyUrl,
        SellPrice = p.SellPrice.ToString("N2")/*Error Here changed type to string*/,
        DiscountPercentage = p.DiscountPercentage,
        Votes = p.Votes,
        TotalRating = p.TotalRating
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you return 400, or 400.00 should not matter for anything mathematical so I'm assuming that this is regarding displaying a decimal to a user. In this case you can supply a [string format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to decimal's ToString().

```
decimal number = 400m;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("N2")); // Outputs 400.00
```

This will always return up to two decimal places. Please note however, that it is no longer a number at this point, but a string. If you are using the webservices' JSON for both display and math then I suggest returning the decimal, and formatting the string client side through javscript `number.toFixed(2);`

Comment: I tried you're example but I get a Linq To Entities error in my code do you know what work around can be done

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you were using LINQ to Entities - let's see what we can do about that now that we've got that bit of information aswell

Comment: Im using jquery to present that data into a table maybe javascript has to format it. if so how would i format in javascript or jquery

Comment: To do the same in javascript all you'd have to do is [call](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) `toFixed(2)` on the number.